# Nested php loops used to parse CSV file input into DB - SQL insert statement fails at arbitrary cycle

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops, filter

I have an issue with a function I am writing whereby I take a large csv file and input it into an array 2d array.

The csv file an export from a database table with various records,

The following are the steps the function carries out:

```
//A. get temporary file path
//B. place file into array as a long string
//C. parse string into array based on rows (\r)
//D. parse row strings into arrays for columns (,)


//1. Query db for price codes
//1.1 Loop through CSV top row to find price code x axis position
//2. Loop through price codes SQL
    //2.1 Loop through price codes column from CSV file
        //2.1.1 IF match price code
            //2.1.2 Check if id match on price list array
                //2.1.3 Add record to prices table
                        //Success
                        //Failure (this could kill the loop maybe)
//3. Close loops and close sql connection
```

Price codes are codes relating to what geographical area the price is applicable too.

The function loops through all the price codes in the database

Within the price code loop a sub loops sifts through the csv array looking for records with a price code matching the current loop.

When a match is found, input into database

Here is the code:
[Click for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbU0K.png)

I output debugging text every step of the loop to see if everything executes successfully.

The loop executes correctly - however for some unknown reason after a certain point the mysqli query doesn’t add further records to the database.

How could this happen? even when it doesn’t give an error, and the SQL query string which is outputted to the page looks intact.

Comment: It's possibly the `die()` statement that ends script or a timeout issue or still others. Without reproducible example, really hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running pure SQL by uploading all your data pieces, `csv_array` and `onPriceList` into MySQL temp tables (regularly cleaned out if they regularly change) and run one SQL query, avoiding nested `foreach` loops and `if` logic.

You can easily upload csv data into MySQL in one call using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` (or insert with PHP iterations):

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/csv/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE csvdata
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Then, run one straightforward append query (adjust below to align to actual table and field names as screenshot does not show):

```sql
INSERT INTO prices (PriceCode, SellingPrice, StockCode)
SELECT c.priceCodePosition, c.pricePosition, c.model_idPosition
FROM csvdata c
INNER JOIN pricecodes p
   ON c.model_idPosition = p.Code
WHERE c.model_idPosition IN (SELECT p.prices FROM onPriceList)
```

---

In case you need to capture the records that do not match logic (as you need with the echo statements), run the antithetical statement (which would be records that are not appended):

```sql
SELECT c.priceCodePosition, c.pricePosition, c.model_idPosition
FROM csvdata c
LEFT JOIN pricecodes p
   ON c.model_idPosition = p.Code
WHERE c.model_idPosition IS NULL 
   OR c.model_idPosition NOT IN (SELECT p.prices FROM onPriceList)
```